# Excel 2010 - Cell and Shapes Coloring - My ideas

Tags: excel, vba, colors

Excel 2003 had a simple ...interior.colorindex and only 56 numbers. But, this is changed with Excel 2010 for better control.

Now while developing a program.. which is supposed to copy a cell color (in VBA) and put the same color of the cell to an Excel Shape depending on the cell contents... i was lost with several different objects like this:

For the Cell:

```
Sheets("Config").Range("E1").Interior.ThemeColor = 10
Sheets("Config").Range("E1").Interior.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
```

For the Shape:

```
Activesheet.shapes("R3").fill.forecolor.objectthemecolor = 7
Activesheet.shapes("R3").fill.forecolor.brightness = 0.6
Activesheet.shapes("R3").fill.forecolor.schemecolor = 42
Activesheet.shapes("R3").fill.forecolor.tintandshade (and this doesn't even work)
```

Comment: It's OK (and even sometimes encouraged) to ask a question and answer it yourself, but you should split it into two distinct parts - a question and an answer. What you've posted here is all posted as "question" when it seems like most of should actually be in an "answer".

Comment: I agree to what awoodland mentioned. This question doesn't need to be answered. Please close this question.

Comment: As @awoodland said. Please remove your answer from the question and add it as an actual answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a better simpler way which don't require all the above different naming..

All you need is:

```
range("b9").Interior.Color
```

which will return a long... like this for example: 682978 (of the hex color in decimal)

And, you can set the color for the shape like this:

```
.Shapes(xName).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 682978 (some variable)
```

Other useful notes are:

```
range("h1").Interior.Color = rgb(0,123,124)
```

and, for printing in console

```
? rgb(0, 123, 124)
```